# End input of a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to take input of an array of strings (each string is a question)
and my code is as follows:

```
void read_quest()throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("enter the questions(enter null to end input operation)");
    for(int i = 0;; i++)
      {
        question[i]=in.readLine();
        if(question[i].equals("\0")==true)
        {
            n=i-1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but the loop is never exited
i am using bluej as it is for a school project(we are allowed to use only bluej)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you don't have to deal with `"\0"`. Also, it [might be hard for the user to input `NUL` character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124786/how-to-simulate-nul-character-from-keyboard) anyway.

The method `in.readLine()` returns a `String` that was input by the user, excluding the end-of-line character that terminates it.

- If you want to check if user presses Enter without entering any text, compare the input with the empty string `""` like this:

  `if ("".equals(question[i]))`
- If you want to check for `Ctrl+D` ([End of transmission character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character)), compare with `\4` [as said in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837823/read-input-until-controld): 

  `if ("\4".equals(question[i]))`.
  ***Note:*** cannot test this in Eclipse, and the user will have to press Enter anyway after Ctrl+D

Note that if the user uses `Ctrl-C`, your `readLine()` will return `null`, and your program will exit not long after.

---

**Side notes:**

- you don't need `==true`, because `x.equals(y)` already is a `boolean`.
- `"literal".equals(variable)` is safer than `variable.equals("literal")`: if your `variable` is `null`, the first version just yields `false` without crashing, while the second version throws `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 3):

Compare it with anything other than **"\0"** and you are good to go, you have to do this because null cannot be entered

Answer (score 1):

`in.readLine()` returns null if there are no more lines

```
void read_quest()throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("enter the questions(enter null to end input operation)");
    for(int i = 0;; i++)
      {
        question[i]=in.readLine();
        if(question[i]==null)
        {
            n=i-1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the end of input, you can ask user just press `enter` without a string. so you can check for empty string or string length(0)

```
if (question[i].length() == 0) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They cannot enter null - perhaps you meant a blank string? Try

```
if(question[i].equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

`in.readLine()` is the method of inputstream it returns the line of text otherwise it returns the null so you have to check null condition.

```
if(question[i] == null)
```

Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You comparing the null in wrong way in Java, you need to change the if condition as follows:

```
if(question[i]==null)
```