# Create an actionlistener(?) in Java

Tags: java

So I searched Stackoverflow, but couldn't find any actual answer that I got. If there's already an answer to this question, please tell me.

I have a class with a showDescription method. This prints a string variable.

I require this method to be called whenever the "d" key is pressed, in the main method. So, what would the code be to implement the key press/down event?

Comment: You don't need an ActionListener. You need either a `DocumentListener` or key bindings, depending on what you are trying to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok. I think my question explains what is required pretty clearly, but anyway: When the "d" key is pressed, a certain method is supposed to be called.

Comment: Then you need [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: If you want to do this from within Swing, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), if want this to be a global/OS level event, you need to invetsigate a JNI/JNA based solution

Comment: could someone give a simpler example? I don't really get what to do

Answer (score 1):

Do this if you have a swing application:

```
f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) && ((e.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK) != 0)) {
                    System.out.println("woot!");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            }
        });
```

you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970765/java-detect-ctrlx-key-combination-on-a-jtree) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851505/how-can-a-keylistener-detect-key-combinations-e-g-alt-1-1)

If you have a console application then use:

[Read Input until control+d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837823/read-input-until-controld)