# Java while loop not breaking when using HasNextLine()

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I know that there's similar questions, but my while loop times out when using HasNextLine() and none of the solutions online have fixed it so far.

```
public static main(String [] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;

    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String input = s.nextLine();

        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        // Do other stuff
        result += sum;
    }
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

I've tried clicking Ctrl-D in the terminal, using while(!s.equals(SENTINEL)). Also note that I have an if statement that should break the loop when the next line is empty, but it doesn't break.

Comment: This answer should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412853/8700809

Comment: Will exit the loop on empty line (break) or Ctrl-D (Linux console). Theoretically if System.in was taken from a custom console, and `hasNextLine()` would be blocking? Or if the lineSeparator System property was customized? Try Scannor on a text file, so you have more control on the actual data.

Comment: On Windows, use ctrl-z. Because it's Windows. And Windows is ***special***.

Comment: Tediously, it's `Ctrl-Z, ENTER` on Windows in a console window.

Answer (score 0):

The loop terminates when you press 'enter' without inputting any text. So, if you write a string and press enter, the loop will iterate; if you press enter again without typing anything it will terminate.